# What is wrong with this piece of PHP code? This is for an email template. (I am completely new to PHP)

Tags: php

I am trying to make an email template with PHP on Wordpress.
`<p><?php esc_html_e( 'We have finished processing your order.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>`
The above piece of code works just fine. However when I **replace** it with multiple lines such as:

```
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'Your order has been delivered.’, 'woocommerce'); ?></p> <?php 
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'We sincerely hope you loved the product(s). Looking forward to your feedback – please leave us a review on https://www.facebook.com/pg/daffodilsgirls/reviews/.', 'woocommerce'); ?></p> <?php
<p><?php esc_html_e('Once again, we thank you for shopping at https://www.branddaffodils.com. We hope to see you again soon!', 'woocommerce'); ?></p> <?php
```

This set does not work and causes an error. May I know why? Also, how am I supposed to **make a link** and **do next line** in php in this code?

Comment: Please add the complete error message to your post.

Comment: Well, by giving an error, I mean that it does not work. The email does not send because there is some problem with these set of lines.

Comment: [Enable debug mode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info), then you will get an useful error message. :)

Comment: You have paragraph tags inside the PHP escaping that could be causing a problem.  Instead of `, 'woocommerce'); ?></p> <?php` you should have `, 'woocommerce'); ?></p>`.  Plain HTML is not valid PHP and is likely causing your error.  But yes, Fuxia is correct.  Get a good error message if you want to know with certainty what the problem is.

Comment: PHP is "escaped" from the markup and processed by the server.  `<?php` opens the pair and `?>` closes.  Each of your lines ends with an opening `<?php` which it should not.

Comment: The error log will log your PHP problems separately from the front-end of your site. 
 See the link Fuxia provided to use the log.  PHP basics can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php

Comment: Thank you! I think this will solve it. Also can you tell me how to activate/the syntax for adding a link with php?